# How to use Jquery .on() method on multiple dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I am trying to attach an .on() click method to elements that I create dynamically. These elements each have a Bootstrap popover in them which acts as a menu with options for each element. The popovers are also created dynamically.

To make the menu work, I assign a unique number to each element and when an option from the menu is clicked, that unique number is extracted as a way to match the menu and it's options to the element. That way when I click the 'delete' option, it knows which element to delete.

However when I create multiple elements and try to extract the unique number, I only get the number of the first element.

HTML:

```
<div class="scenario-group" id="scenario-group-0">
<div class="scenario-list" id="scenario-list-0">Egypt</div>
<div style="display:none;" name="0" id="scenario-options-box-0" class="scenario-options-box" scn-box="0">
    <button type="button" id="show-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="0">Show</button>
    <button type="button" id="rename-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="0">Rename</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="0">Delete</button>
</div>
<div>
  <a tabindex="0" role="button" style="left:22px; top:2px;" name="0" class="scenario-btn" id="scenario-options-btn-0" scn-box-btn="0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="focus" data-original-title="" title="">
  <i style="color:#444444;" class="fas fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="scenario-group" id="scenario-group-1">
<div class="scenario-list" id="scenario-list-1">Nigeria</div>
<div style="display:none;" name="1" id="scenario-options-box-1" class="scenario-options-box" scn-box="1">
    <button type="button" id="show-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="1">Show</button>
    <button type="button" id="rename-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="1">Rename</button>
    <button type="button" id="delete-btn" class="scenario-option-btn btn-light" btn-box="1">Delete</button>
</div>
<div>
  <a tabindex="0" role="button" style="left:22px; top:2px;" name="1" class="scenario-btn" id="scenario-options-btn-1" scn-box-btn="1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-trigger="focus" data-original-title="" title="">
  <i style="color:#444444;" class="fas fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
    $(document).on('click',".scenario-option-btn", function() {

    var btnVal = $(this).text();
    var btnID = $(this).attr("btn-box")
    var scnID = $("#scenario-list-" + btnID + "").text();
    })
```

The return values for btnVal are correct, however the value for btnID will always return 0 and I am struggling to see why.

Is this the correct way to assign event handlers to multiple dynamically created elements?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `btnId` is always `0`?

Comment: You should not create custom attributes, use `data-btn-box` instead of `btn-box`. But that shouldn't cause this problem.

Comment: You have invalid HTML here: `<div class="scenario-list" id="scenario-list-0" <div="" name="0">Egypt</div>`

Comment: Is the related scenario list always the previous DIV? You can use `$(this).closest(".scenario-options-box").prev().text()`.

Comment: Thanks for the invalid HTML flag, just noticed it myself. Yes btnID always returns 0.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your question about the related scenario list. The entire HTML from '.scenario-group' is dynamic. So there is no '.scenario-list' until it is created.

Comment: But you're creating both the scenario list and scenario options box dynamically at the same time, aren't you? Are they always created next to each other, or could the related `scenario-list-X` be anywhere?

Comment: Could you please edit the question to fix the typo and HTML?

Comment: Yes they're created at the same time and next to each other.

Comment: Then why wouldn't my suggestion work, instead of needing to use an attribute?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] demonstrating the problem? It looks like your code should work.

Comment: Your `<div>` and `</div>` tags don't balance properly. You're missing the `</div>` for the `scenario-group` DIVs.

Comment: When I fixed the HTML, your code worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ge871ypf/5/

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the HTML but am still getting the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199337/discussion-between-ajay-ubhi-and-barmar).